# How to access nested dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I can print this in the debugger:

```
(lldb) print params["message"]!
([String : String]) $R5 = 2 key/value pairs {
  [0] = (key = "body", value = "iPadUser has started a new stream")
  [1] = (key = "title", value = "Stream started")
}
```

But I am trying to figure out how to access the body and title separately.

I construct params in this way:

```
            let recipients = ["custom_ids":[recips]]
            let notificationDetails = "hello there"
            let content = [
                "title":title,
                "body":details
            ]
            let params: [String:Any] = [
                "group_id":"stream_requested",
                "recipients": recipients,
                "message": content
            ]
```

Comment: What is your actual question? I don't understand.

Comment: how would I print just the title, or the body?  I have tried print params["message"]![title]! but that does not work.  I am trying to access the individual values

Comment: content["title"] and content["body"] ?

Comment: When the dictionary values are set to Any, you must explicitly set the type

Comment: Oh, i see, so maybe I would be better off not using Any and user String:String since I now they the type.  Then in the code I can do something like let myTitle = content["title"] ... Correct?

Comment: Well it depends. If you use String:Any, it's better if your dictionary can contain any other values, like stored dictionary and so... best way is to unwrap the nested dictionary and then when you get to your values cast them as their right type.

Comment: Ok, yes, i think i got it, one more thing... you are right as recipients is a string array.  So, how would I go about access the recipients list?  Would I cast it to a String[]

Comment: You have the answer in my answer, if you like it, you can mark it as best answer since the other guy just copied mine :D Or ask below the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print((params["message"] as! [String: Any])["title"] as! String)
```

You need to cast the Dictionary value as specific type, since the compiler doesn't know what to expect. (Please mind that you mustn't use force unwrap in other way than example code.)

Considering you need to fetch array values when recipients dictionary looks like this:

```
let recipients = ["custom_ids":["recipe1", "recipe2", "etc"]]
```

get to the ids like this:

```
guard let recipients = params["recipients"] as? [String: Any],
      let customIDs = recipients["custom_ids"] as? [String] 
else { return }

for id in customIDs {
    print(id) // Gets your String value
}
```